Optimal Nest.js Architecture for Large-Scale Applications with 60+ Tables
Initially, the project had a smaller scope, but it has since expanded significantly, qualifying it as a large-scale endeavor.
Presently, the architecture of my Nest.js app is structured as follows:
modules/
    ModuleA/
       /entities
         A
     A.module.ts
     A.controller.ts
     A.service.ts
    ModuleB/
      /entities
       B
     B.module.ts
     B.controller.ts
     B.service.ts

While this approach follows the entity-per-module paradigm, I recognize that it may not be the most optimal. Hence, I am seeking guidance to rectify this oversight.
Could you please advise on the best architecture for organizing my Nest.js code, especially considering its significant size? The first version is expected to involve approximately 60 tables.

There are numerous patterns you can adapt according to your use case. Since you haven't provided any context, I'll mention some current trends and historically proven useful patterns.
My assumptions are:

You have a monolith.
You are using the three-tier model literally for every part of your code.
The three-tier model is becoming an obstacle as your monolith grows.

DDD - Domain Driven Design
If your app contains a lot of domain logic and complex business logic, it's widely advised to follow domain-driven design principles.
Hexagonal Architecture
Besides your domain logic, if your monolith is becoming gigantic, it's also advised to adapt the application, domain, infra, and presenters structure both to your folder structure and overall module structure, instead of using the controller, service, model structure. This is a big topic with different concepts and solutions for different problems, so do a nice research on this architecture.
Diverse Modularization Strategies
Where you should pack your classes and code into a module is not defined by your entity or domain; it's defined by many variables.
You might need to divide based on feature (feature-based modularization).
Real-world examples:

Product Catalog Module: Manages product listings, categories, and search functionality.
Order Management Module: Manages the shopping cart, order processing, and payment integration.
Review and Rating Module: Handles user reviews and ratings for products.
Reporting Module: Generates sales reports and user activity reports.

Maybe domain-driven modularization, where your module exports a range of services (in this context, service classes provide access to domain logic and behaviors).
Real-world example (banking application):

Customer Domain: Handles customer information and customer-related operations.
Account Domain: Manages different types of bank accounts, account operations, and transactions.
Loan Domain: Manages loan products, loan applications, and repayment schedules.
Transaction Domain: Handles all types of financial transactions, transaction history, and auditing.

Or maybe modularization based on technical responsibilities that your infrastructure layer might need to delegate to another module.

Logging Module
Authentication Module
Notification Module
Caching Module: Exports services which provide caching strategies, cache invalidation, and distributed caching mechanisms

CQRS
Sometimes, even the way you write and organize your services in the domain layer can cause problems. It seems like you are moving away from CRUD operations to more complex operations that don't fit those four categories. Therefore, I recommend changing your perspective from a create-read-update-delete mindset to a command-query mindset. Martin Fowler's article on this topic is highly recommended.
There is No Bulletproof Solution
I know, mentioned a lot. But also forgotten a lot.
Just to ensure we're on the right track, remember that the only bulletproof solution is that there is no bulletproof solution.

Could you please advise on the best architecture for organizing my Nest.js code?

When I suggested using DDD, I specifically recommended it for use cases where you have complex business logic. The same goes for other principles and patterns. You might not want to use DDD if you are trying to write an optimized action-trigger for your CI/CD infrastructure pipeline (Utility or Infrastructure Applications).
